# How to check for out of order packets for MPTCP in mininet?

Tags: mininet, mptcp

I am trying to test some MPTCP schedulers in mininet and would like to check for the out of order packets (at the connection level) on the receiver side. I tried it with Wireshark(v2.4.5) and monitored the Data Sequence Number (DSN) for dupACKs but I believe it is showing the results at the subflow level. Has anybody tried this in mininet? I am looking forward to any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

DSN and DataAck are MPTCP-level values. If you capture traffic at the receiver, you can plot the dsn to look for out-of-order arrival. (mptcp.dsn filter in wireshark IIRC)